# Peer Discovery in PoA with Containers with dynamic IPs

Tags: go-ethereum, peers, bootnodes

I have a small PoA network setup in Docker containers locally and, for the most part, have the bootnode and peer discovery pieces working. I'm running into trouble when my mining containers reload (for whatever reason) and subsequently come up on a new IP.

On launch, the containers lookup the bootnode IP and then start geth, but the miners fail to find any peers. Looking at verbose logs, it seems like the nodes are trying to re-connect to the peers that they were originally connected to, but fail because those IPs are no longer listening.

It seems like the miners try to drop the connections, but they never establish peer relationships with the newly rolled miners.

Any ideas? I've trolled through documentation and nothing has stood out so far.

From continued reading, I think I can draw conclusions from this line in go-ethereum's nodedb library https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/f79cce5de98332e6d54eb298fce85c69d1082ee2/p2p/enode/nodedb.go#L59.

I'll try turning that value way down (to like 10 minutes) and seeing if that helps me.